# RESTFUL endpoint for removing foreign key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rest, api, routes

I have a Rails API. What is the common practice (route and controller action) to remove foreign key in a REST API? I mean not deleting any resources just setting the foreign key to `null` on a one-to-one relationship.

For instance I have a vehicle and the vehicle has one customer.

If I was to delete the customer it would be:

`DELETE /vehicles/:id/customer`

If I just wanna set the `vehicle_id: null` on the customer what endpoint and controller I should use?

Comment: What are the associations between these models?

Comment: One to one, foreign key on customer model (vehicle_id).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what the *common practice* is, but you could set up your `routes.rb` something like:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  ...

  resources :customers do 
    resources :vehicles, shallow: true
    member do
      put :remove_vehicle
    end
  end

  ...

end
```

Which will give you something like:

```
      customer_vehicles GET    /customers/:customer_id/vehicles(.:format)           vehicles#index
                        POST   /customers/:customer_id/vehicles(.:format)           vehicles#create
   new_customer_vehicle GET    /customers/:customer_id/vehicles/new(.:format)       vehicles#new
           edit_vehicle GET    /vehicles/:id/edit(.:format)                         vehicles#edit
                vehicle GET    /vehicles/:id(.:format)                              vehicles#show
                        PATCH  /vehicles/:id(.:format)                              vehicles#update
                        PUT    /vehicles/:id(.:format)                              vehicles#update
                        DELETE /vehicles/:id(.:format)                              vehicles#destroy
remove_vehicle_customer PUT    /customers/:id/remove_vehicle(.:format)              customers#remove_vehicle
              customers GET    /customers(.:format)                                 customers#index
                        POST   /customers(.:format)                                 customers#create
           new_customer GET    /customers/new(.:format)                             customers#new
          edit_customer GET    /customers/:id/edit(.:format)                        customers#edit
               customer GET    /customers/:id(.:format)                             customers#show
                        PATCH  /customers/:id(.:format)                             customers#update
                        PUT    /customers/:id(.:format)                             customers#update
                        DELETE /customers/:id(.:format)                             customers#destroy
```

In which case you will add a `remove_vehicle` action to your `CustomersController`. In that action, you will have access to `params[:id]` which you can use to find your `@customer` and then do something like:

```
class CustomersController < ApplicationController

  ...

  def remove_vehicle
    @customer = Customer.find(params[:id])
    @customer.update(vehicle_id: nil)
    redirect_to :somewhere
  end

  ...

end
```

Comment: Yeah, this would be the easy way. I am just not sure if this is the convention. I don't really like to use random action names, but rather put things in a separate controller, so it's easier to discover and it follows SRP. I am just not sure what controlller/route I should use. Btw the relationship is reversed in your comment. The vehicle has one customer, so the customer has the foreign_key.

Comment: So, if you really want to go bare bones about it, why not just use `PUT    /customers/:id`? Something like `/customers/1?vehicle_id=` (which I believe will give you `{"vehicle_id"=>nil}` in your params).

Comment: Also, as to convention, the guide on [Adding More RESTful Routes](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-more-restful-actions) talks about exactly the `remove_vehicle` sort of thing. So, I imagine it's pretty conventional.

Comment: I might do with the PUT, I am just not sure if that is the best way :(. This is pretty good: http://jeromedalbert.com/how-dhh-organizes-his-rails-controllers/